# Partial download of file (Just what changed)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, download, memcached, partial

I do an url fetch to get info from an online txt file. It's a big file (like 2Mb and counting) that gets modified all the time, automatically.

I'm using memcache from Google App Engine to keep the data for a while. But for each new request, the incoming bandwith increased, and I started to get Over Quota error.

I need a way to make a partial download of this file downloading only whats changed, instead of all the file.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: Can you split the file and cache smaller chunks? What can of data is there? Some kind of logs? For instance, can the data that was stored yesterday still be modified today, or is it going to remain as-is forever?

Answer (score 1):

Only if you know what part of the file has been changed.

For example, if you know that the file is only appended to, then you could use a [HTTP Range request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.35) to request only the end of the file.

If you have no way of knowing where the file has been changed, then it would work only if the server sent you a patch or delta to a previous version.